# Why can't I install a module from the CPAN within Cygwin?

Tags: perl, cygwin, cpan

I'm attempting to install [`Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser) from the CPAN.

When installing it via:

```
cpan install Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser
```

I get the following unhelpful error during build:

```
Writing Makefile for Digest::Perl::MD5
/bin/sh: 0: command not found
make: *** [blib/lib/Digest/Perl/.exists] Error 127
/usr/bin/make  -- NOT OK
```

[`Digest::Perl::MD5`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Digest::Perl::MD5) is a dependency.  Does anyone know what is going on?

---

Interesting error when attempting to download the distribution and install it without `cpan`, executing `Makefile.PL` gives:

> Unable to find a perl 5 (by these names: /usr/bin/perl.exe perl.exe perl5.exe perl5.8.7.exe miniperl.exe, in these dirs: . /usr/bin /usr/X11R6/bin /usr/local/bin

(followed by the rest of my $PATH. Doing a which perl yields: `/usr/bin/perl`. `perl -v` gives a version of 5.8.7.

Comment: You might be missing cygwin packages required for the installation of some of the perl modules -- Default cygwin install doesn't have much.  You probably need at least make and gcc4

Comment: `make` and `gcc` definitely exist, in `/usr/bin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `perl` executable did not have full execute permissions! (What?)

From [this blog](http://blog.multiplay.co.uk/2009/07/perl-makefile-pl-errors-with-unable-to-find-a-perl-5-on-cygwin/):

> The fix was a simple chmod a+x /usr/bin/perl.exe for anyone who comes across this issue.

I got a `Permission Denied` when I did that. I used the Windows Explorer to recursively set 0777 permissions in `%CYGWIN%`, since `make install` was failing due to lack of permissions.